# How can I change the colors of the points based on the areas of the coordinate plane using python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

im just new at python programming and i want to change color of dots in chart based on areas of coordinate plane like (∞,∞)-->green (-∞,∞)-->yellow etc. Datas have to come from a csv file. i tried some if-else conditions but couldnt do it. here datas from csv

```
 X,Y
 1,3
-8,-8
 8,8
 8,-4
-8,-7
-14,-13
-8,-7
-16,-16
```

and here my code, i tried some absurd things with arrays sorry for that

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import csv
import pandas as pd


path2Csv="sonuçlar.csv"
with open(path2Csv,newline='\n') as g:
   reader=csv.reader(g)
   dataResult=list(reader)[1:] 

col_list=["X","Y"]
df = pd.read_csv(path2Csv, usecols=col_list)
xleft=[0]*len(dataResult)   
xright=[0]*len(dataResult)
yup=[0]*len(dataResult)
ydown=[0]*len(dataResult)
eu1=df["X"]
eu2=df["Y"]
for i in range(len(dataResult)):
   if eu1[i]<0:
      xleft[i]=eu1[i]
   if eu1[i]>0:
      xright[i]=eu1[i]
   if eu2[i]<0:
      ydown[i]=eu2[i]
   if eu2[i]>0:
      yup[i]=eu2[i]

plt.scatter(xleft,yup,c="yellow")
plt.scatter(xleft,ydown,c="blue")
plt.scatter(xright,yup,c="gray")
plt.scatter(xright,ydown,c="green")#should i create new arrays from df["X"] and df["Y"] or 
                                   #use something else instead of scatter?
plt.show()
```

it would be super when you can give me some hints

Comment: i found a way to do it now, but im open to your suggestions still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main idea to change points color is

- Calculate the color by `x` and `y`
- Save the color into a list
- Call `plt.scatter` with calculated color list

I wrote a demo to draw a color table as below.

Using [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) to draw gradient color is easier :)

[image]

```
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xList = []
yList = []
colors = []
count = 50
for x in range(0, count):
    for y in range(0, count):
        xList.append(x)
        yList.append(y)
        hue = x / count
        saturation = (count - y) / count
        colors.append(matplotlib.colors.hsv_to_rgb([hue, saturation, 1]))

plt.scatter(xList, yList, c=colors)
plt.show()
```